# Laravel 5.4 Type error: Too few arguments to function. 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I want to implement queue in sending emails. I have a function of register as

```
public function register(CustomerRequest $request)
    {
        \Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Begins");
        $parameter = 'This is parameter';
        dispatch(new SendWelcomeEmail($parameter));

        \Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Ends");
    }
```

and I have created a job inside `App\Jobs\SendWelcomeEmail`. Which looks like below:

```
class SendWelcomeEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        #
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle($parameter)
    {
        Log::info($parameter);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting error like

`Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\SendWelcomeEmail::handle(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in`

Answer (score 0):

`$parameter` not for `handle()` method, but for its constructor

```
class SendWelcomeEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $parameter;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($parameter)
    {
        $this->parameter = $parameter;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info($this->parameter);
    }
}
```